# Parsing date formats

Tags: android

I am parsing dates out of RSS data and so am I have a date that doesnt seem to parse:
The input date string is : **Fri, 28 Sept 2012 08:30:00 -0330**

So it looks like **EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z** should parse it, but it produces an error

Can anyone suggest a date format or strategy to parse this date? 
Fri, 28 Sept 2012 08:30:00 -0330

```
Cannot parse :Fri, 28 Sept 2012 08:30:00 -0330|| with format:EEE, dd MMM yy HH:mm:ss Z
Cannot parse :Fri, 28 Sept 2012 08:30:00 -0330|| with format:EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z
Cannot parse :Fri, 28 Sept 2012 08:30:00 -0330|| with format:dd MMM yy HH:mm:ss Z
Cannot parse :Fri, 28 Sept 2012 08:30:00 -0330|| with format:dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z
Cannot parse :Fri, 28 Sept 2012 08:30:00 -0330|| with format:EEE, dd MMM yy HH:mm Z
Cannot parse :Fri, 28 Sept 2012 08:30:00 -0330|| with format:EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm Z
Cannot parse :Fri, 28 Sept 2012 08:30:00 -0330|| with format:EEE, dd MMM yy HH:mm:ss
Cannot parse :Fri, 28 Sept 2012 08:30:00 -0330|| with format:EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss
Cannot parse :Fri, 28 Sept 2012 08:30:00 -0330|| with format:yy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'
Cannot parse :Fri, 28 Sept 2012 08:30:00 -0330|| with format:yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'
Cannot parse :Fri, 28 Sept 2012 08:30:00 -0330|| with format:yy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'
Cannot parse :Fri, 28 Sept 2012 08:30:00 -0330|| with format:yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'
Cannot parse :Fri, 28 Sept 2012 08:30:00 -0330|| with format:yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ
Cannot parse :Fri, 28 Sept 2012 08:30:00 -0330|| with format:yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ
Cannot parse :Fri, 28 Sept 2012 08:30:00 -0330|| with format:EEE, dd MMM yy HH:mm
Cannot parse :Fri, 28 Sept 2012 08:30:00 -0330|| with format:EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm
Cannot parse :Fri, 28 Sept 2012 08:30:00 -0330|| with format:EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z
```

Comment: You should really post your parsing code.

Comment: is MMM the number of letters? I don't remember :p Sept has four though.

Comment: it just use simpledatformat.parse - nothing special there

Comment: look like its just invalid 'Sept' doesnt seem to parse at all

Comment: anyone know if 'Sept' will ever parse?

Comment: If the date you're trying to parse doesn't match your locale, you'll get those kind of errors. "Sept" doesn't work because it should be "Sep" (if the locale is US).

Answer (score 0):

```
String str="Fri, 28 Sept 2012 08:30:00 -0330";
Date date =new  Date();
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat();
try
{ 
date = df.parse(str);
} 
catch (ParseException e) 
{

e.printStackTrace();
}

System.out.println(date);
```